# How i can create object view-model from GeofenceBroadcastReceiver class. || Android - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-jetpack, geofence

I want change some of the colors in my app directly when user enter the geofence area and then when they leave the geofence the colors return to normal.

My problem.

[image: 1]

Comment: Have your broadcast receiver update some singleton (e.g., a repository) to reflect the state change. Have that singleton supply the information downstream to your viewmodel via a reactive API (e.g., `StateFlow`, `LiveData`).

Comment: can you explain more with examples?

Comment: I cover singleton repositories in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-arch-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/). I cover using Koin for dependency inversion in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-di-001.html), and that will help make it easier for you to set up testable repositories while still allowing access to them from your receiver and viewmodel.